# CLS tool is failing? data does not match

Tags: difference, pagespeed, cls

I am trying to improve the website that I am in charge of, but using the Page Speed ​​tool https://pagespeed.web.dev/ shows me that the CLS for desktop is already 0 (zero) and in the Above it shows me "Evaluation not passed" for the page https://tiendasch.com.mx/discos-de-estado-solido-ssd
Has anyone had this happen and how can I fix it? since before it showed me the CLS at 0.43 now at 0 but above it says "test failed" for the CLS, I attach images

[CLS problem page speed wrong calculate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCaK8.png)

[Prueba CLS page speed cant aproved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNpXu.png)

I already corrected and moved the code to improve the CLS to 0 but it still shows "test failed" for CLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a lot of help on the web but not something or a tool that tells you exactly where the problem is, the best help was chrome tools for developers that has a page loading recorder so that helped me and I could see what it was in the loading of the iframe, which is why I moved or deleted it for testing, currently I deleted it but we will add it later in a lower position to see how it goes.